# SOAP + Adobe Scene7 Uploading assets by way of HTTP POSTs

Tags: soap, http-post, adobe, scene7

I'm trying to Uploading assets by way of HTTP POSTs to the UploadFile Servlet in Adobe Scene7 and for the life of me cannot get it to work no matter what I try. Here is their documentation:

https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/s7/ips_api/c_http_post.html

I usually get the following error / response:

"Header section has more than 10240 bytes (maybe it is not properly terminated)"
https://gist.github.com/erickertz/8b50c503fd0e75fdb962515051253097

One thing to note is that I could not get their example working with separate "auth" and "uploadParams" parts. I instead imported their WSDL in SOAPUI which had the following form that seemed to work:

https://gist.github.com/erickertz/a4eb13e35f7709c6e5d2b4721b08510a

Here is an example of one of my failed requests:

https://gist.github.com/erickertz/3feccd53b9cb63bdba40de86c86da289

I admit that I'm not all that familiar with SOAP in general but this is driving me nuts :( Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, hope this saves someone else some time. I found a somewhat unrelated post here that had the same error with SOAP and a .NET application:

https://community.tableau.com/thread/213098

Issue was the service only recognized "/r/n" as newline characters. I converted all of my "/n" characters to "/r/n" and it works! Thanks Adobe!